# wordpress - how can I send emails to other url with contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 in Wordpress for contact forms and other similar forms. I want to send the emails to other URLs (not e-mail address). Is it possible?

Comment: email to URL ?what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to send the email to a specific mailing address url.. not an email address..